# Visualize duplicate ID (unique column) from dataset

Tags: dataset, visualization

I have a dataset contains ID and year of their occurrence. This is the sample of my dataset:

| ID | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2018 |
| 1234 | 2019 |
| 5678 | 2017 |
| 5678 | 2020 |
| .... | .... |

I would like to visualize the ID's and the year when they are occurring. Is there any idea how I should visualize it using Python? Fyi the dataset has 48 ID and every ID always occur 2 times (which means they occur in 2 years).

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas you can use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to create an aggregate for every ID and counting the year where the ID occurs in your dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "id": [1234, 1234, 5678, 5678],
    "year": [2018, 2019, 2017, 2020]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_grouped = df.groupby(["id", "year"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print(df_grouped)
```

Where [`size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) counts the occurrences and [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) creates a new level of column labels whose inner-most level consists of the pivoted index labels.

Outputs:

```
year  2017  2018  2019  2020
id
1234     0     1     1     0
5678     1     0     0     1
```

As for the visualization, I don't know what your preferences are, but I found a bar diagram to be a poor choice. So I opted for a confusion matrix style of visualization:

```py
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sn.set(font_scale=1.4
sn.heatmap(df_grouped, annot=True, square=True, cbar=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: conf_mat]

The benefit of the confusion matrix is, for example, if ID=1234 occurs twice in the same year, the count would be 2 instead of 1 in the visualization.